# How To Scrape Multiple URLs With Selenium and BeautifulSoup4 In Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been messing around with a few different solutions for how to scrape multiple URLs with Selenium, BS4 and UserAgent and so far I've been able to scrape 1 URL to extract exactly what I want. It's just when it comes to 1+ URL I'm having trouble.

At the moment, I have this code below that is working to scrape the first page. If you change the `urls` argument to just `url`, uncomment out the `url` variable, get rid of the `for url in urls`  and remove the indentation of the `for content in sel_soup` loop, you can see what I mean.

And I would like to create a loop to scrape, to start, just the 2 web pages and figure when it can loop through those 2 I can append the list with the other URLs I have.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import csv
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium import webdriver

urls = ["https://www.guitarcenter.com/Used/Bass.gc#pageName=used-page&N=18171+1076&Nao=0&recsPerPage=90&postalCode=02494&radius=100&profileCountryCode=US&profileCurrencyCode=USD","https://www.guitarcenter.com/Used/Bass.gc#pageName=used-page&N=18171+1076&Nao=90&recsPerPage=90&postalCode=02494&radius=100&profileCountryCode=US&profileCurrencyCode=USD","https://www.guitarcenter.com/Used/Bass.gc#pageName=used-page&N=18171+1076&Nao=180&recsPerPage=90&postalCode=02494&radius=100&profileCountryCode=US&profileCurrencyCode=USD"]
#url = "https://www.guitarcenter.com/Used/Bass.gc#pageName=used-page&N=18171+1076&Nao=180&recsPerPage=90&postalCode=02494&radius=100&profileCountryCode=US&profileCurrencyCode=USD"

user_agent = UserAgent()

for url in urls:

    web_r = requests.get(urls)
    web_soup = BeautifulSoup(web_r.text,"html.parser")

        #print(web_soup.findAll("li", class_="product-container")) #finding all of the grid items on the url above - price, photo, image, details and all
        #print(len(web_soup.findAll("li", class_="product-container"))) #printing out the length of the

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(urls)
    html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML") #whats inside of this is a javascript call to get the outer html content of the page
    sel_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")


    for content in sel_soup.findAll("li", class_="product-container"):
            #print(content)

        bass_name = content.find("div", class_="productTitle").text.strip() #pulls the bass guitar name
        print(bass_name)

        prices_new = []
        for i in content.find("span", class_="productPrice").text.split("$"):
            prices_new.append(i.strip())
        bp = prices_new[1]
        print(bp)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop, every iteration over `urls` is working with a single `url` that you are attempting to scrape.

In your calls to `requests.get` and `driver.get` inside the loop however, you are passing it `urls` which isn't a single string `url` but instead the entire list. Try changing `urls` to `url` inside the loop block.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!